# referring to sister element inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to do something like the following (key3 is a combination of 1+2):

```
$a = array(
    'key1' => 5,
    'key2' => 10,
    'key3' => $a['key1']+$a['key2'] // want it to be 15
);
```

How can I do this? Do i need to refer from outside the array and then merge them? Because this doesn't work!

Thanks in advance,

Maurice

Comment: what is the thinking behind this process? Are you creating arrays from something dynamic? Or are you trying to get the SUM of all elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to initialize it that way because PHP hasn't finished going through and initializing the entire array yet, so it can't use its other values yet.

You'll have to do it after initializing the first two elements:

```
$a = array(
    'key1' => 5,
    'key2' => 10
); // At this point, $a is ready for use

$a['key3'] = $a['key1'] + $a['key2']; // Or simply = array_sum($a);
```

Comment: yup, thanks, thought so, i figured to just ask :) THANKS for the quick answer!

Answer (score 5):

The solution proposing to update the table afterward are good, but you can also use variables for your data :

```
$var1 = 5;
$var2 = 10;

$a = array(
    'key1' => $var1,
    'key2' => $var2,
    'key3' => $var1 + $var2
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do:

```
$a = array(
    'key1' => 5,
    'key2' => 10,
    'key3' => 0
);

$a['key3'] = $a['key1']+$a['key2'];
```

It would have the desired result. However, I have a feeling that you are trying to make the third member change when one of the first two change, and I'm afraid you won't be able to accomplish that easily.

Comment: assigning 0 to `'key3'` is useless.

Comment: @Krtek: true, but its nicer this way :)